# Override CSS height 0 and width 0 for iframes

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, iframe, embed

A particular stylesheet file of a WordPress theme has the following code

```
.padder iframe {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

I'm trying to override this in a custom CSS file for displaying video embedded `<iframe>` tags with height & width attributes.

```
<iframe src="...." width="600" height="338" frameborder="0" title="...." webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
```

I tried `auto` for both the `height` and `width` but that makes the iframes smaller.

If this isn't possible in CSS I'm ready to try jquery solutions.

Comment: If you're trying to scale an iframe to the size of it's content, it's not that easy ?

Comment: @adeneo I'm trying to scale the iframe to the static size mentioned in its height and width attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The iframe width and height attributes do not override the CSS ones. try this:

```
<iframe style="width: 600px; height: 338px" ...
```

If that doesn't work, please post the CSS overrides you tried and check that the 0 height/width isn't being loaded after your CSS (try the Firefox or Chrome dev tools)

Have you considered min-width and min-height?

A jQuery solution if all else fails:

```
jQuery('iframe').each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var w = $this.prop('width');
    var h = $this.prop('height');
    $this.css({width: w + 'px', height: h + 'px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to that iframe and try

```
#iframe_id{
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
```

or

```
#iframe_id{
height: 200px !important;
width: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: Using fixed height and width in the stylesheet is not an option. WordPress dynamically sets the dimensions and prints them out on the frontend in the form of height and width attributes.